# If exception retry in Python

Tags: python, try-catch, conditional-statements

How could I go about doing something like this

1. Try to do something.
2. If it works, great, continue with normal flow.
3. If it fails run a function and try again.
4. If it once again fails throw an exception and stop code.

I believe I would have to make use of `try` but I haven't quite come around yet to how to use it in this particular example.

Comment: Does the "something" you want to try have a chance of throwing an exception?  If it doesn't, or it doesn't have to, then by all means avoid using `try` as a means of program flow.

Comment: Yep it does. Basically `something()` is a file-altering operation that, if the file doesn't exist, will blow up. The later mentioned `afunction()` is a file-searching function to correct the file's name so `something()` will run correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you want to do a nested try-catch at all. [Exceptions as control flow are a gnarly anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/189225/54997), and where you can avoid it, you *should*.

In this scenario, avoidance is easy.  In the method that you describe, you want to be sure that a file exists before you do some operations on it.  You also have a method to "correct" the path should it not.  If both attempts fail, then you want to bail out.

With that into account, we would want to use [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) for this.

```
from os.path import isfile

def something(filepath):
    # Don't mutate the parameter if you can help it.
    p = filepath
    if not isfile(p):
        p = correct_path(p)
        if not isfile(p):
            raise Error("Cannot find file {} after correction to {}, aborting.".format(filepath, p))
    with open(p, 'r') as f:
        # Rest of file operations here
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for an arbitrary number of tries; I set it to two since that's what you want.

```
tries = 2
while True:
    try:
        step1()
    except CatchThisException:
        tries -= 1
        if tries:  # if tries != 0
            step3()
            continue  # not necessary, just for clarity
        else:
            raise  # step 4
    else:
        break  # step 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a nested `try catch`:

```
try:
    do_something() #if this works, will skip rest and continue
except:
    do_fix_function() #on error, do extra function
    try:
        do_something() #try again
    except:
        throw error() #if it fails this time, stop and throw an error
```

Note that if your `do_fix_function()` can also fail, you might want to put it inside the second try statement instead

Answer (score -1):

You can use [retrying package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) to solve your retry attempt. Just write a block of code that keeps repeating on failure, until max retries is hit

For example:

import random
from retrying import retry

```
@retry
def do_something_unreliable():
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
    else:
        return "Awesome sauce!"

print do_something_unreliable()
```

Comment: This answer does not work. `@retry` does not allow for a “fix” function to be run between retries (unless you do hacky side effects). The OP also only wants to retry once (which is possible, but not done in this answer). `@retry` is for flaky functions, not deterministic failures. I suggest that next time you read the question more carefully before rushing to judgement and an answer.